# SSIS – How can I fetch custom log entries with my custom log provider?

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssis, etl

I try to understand how the SSIS logging behavior works. I create an SSIS package that has a *Data Flow Task*. The Data Flow Task contains some **custom data flow components**.

One of them overrides the *RegisterLogEntries* method like that:

```cs
public override void RegisterLogEntries()
{
    this.LogEntryInfos.Add("MyCustomLoggerEntryName","Log entry from My Custom Component", DTSLogEntryFrequency.DTSLEF_CONSISTENT);
}
```

And add a log entry in *PreExecute-Method*:

```cs
ComponentMetaData.PostLogMessage(MyLogEntryName, ComponentMetaData.Name, "PreExecute method was fired", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, 0, null);
```

Then I wrote a ***CustomLogProvider*** in the same manner as described by Microsoft.

- [Creating a Custom Log Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-custom-objects/log-provider/creating-a-custom-log-provider?view=sql-server-2017)

I added and enabled my custom log provider in SSDT (SSIS->Logging).

If I ***enable all Events*** (OnError,OnExecStatusChange,OnInformation,…) under Details, then I ***get*** my custom log message in my custom log provider in the log method.

As soon as I ***deactivate at least one event*** under details, I will ***not get*** my custom log entry. It doesn’t matter which event I deactivate.

Does anyone have experience with this problem?